# javascript code on how can I include newLine after .split

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small function to split a string stored in variable `data`,

```
var data = "Apple|Banana";     
var _res = data.split('|');
```

After printing `_res` on the console, it is Printing as `Apple,Banana`.
I am looking for an output where each String is printed on a newline, like,

```
  Apple
  Banana
```

Comment: Can you re-frame the question with proper inputs? What is d.data?

Answer (score 7):

your variable `_res` is an `Array` because it was created after splitting `data`. Hence it is getting printed as it is.

If you want a newline print, you need to manually do it. See below Code as an example.

**Use case when you want to iterate over your input:**

```js
var data = 'Apple|Banana'; //Assuming your data variable

var _res = data.split('|');

_res.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

**Use case when you just want to test in `console` and `alert`:**

```js
var data = 'Apple|Banana'; //Assuming your data variable

var _res = data.split('|').join('\n');

alert(_res);

console.log(_res);
```

Comment: Do u know any thing how can i print in New Line

Comment: @susSam Added Code snippet which does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @susSam  It will be helpful if you can accept the answer since its useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the output as a *string*, in which case you shouldn't use `split` (which returns an array), but `.replace` - replace all `|`s with newlines:

```js
const res = 'Apple|Banana'.replace(/\|/g, '\n');
console.log(res);
```

Or, with `alert`:

```js
const res = 'Apple|Banana'.replace(/\|/g, '\n');
alert(res);
```

Comment: in console Im able to priniting in New Line But My alert Message Showing in Single Line

Comment: It looks to work just fine with `alert` - see second snippet in edit

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation). You can encode special character which will have special meaning in string. 
**`\n`** is used to create line breaks in string.
You can `split()` string by `,` and `join()` by **`\n`**.

```js
let str = 'Apple,Banana'
let newStr = str.split(',').join('\n')
console.log(newStr);
```

```js
let str = 'Apple,Banana'
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = str.split(',').join('<br>')
```

```html
<div><div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding to your problem is correct, you want to split the string using "|" and "," characters. In that case you can use pass regex value in your split method parameter.

```
 var _res = d.data.split(/[,|]+/);
```

You can use this site to generate your regex https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: I doubt that's what OP wanted. The comma comes from converting an array to a string for output.

Comment: You can use this way to convert the array to array of strings through splitting.

Comment: No, you can't call `.split()` on an array.

Comment: I get your point now. Seems like the data is array not a string. If you console.log() your array, it will normally output it as "Apple,Banana". Its because you output an array as a string. But if you want to output the value of each item in your array, then you need to iterate that array and output it one at a time or concat each item into a string with newline added in between.